# What is the effect of splitting the channels in Convolutional neural networks?

Tags: tensorflow

In the following code if I split the input  as [1,4,4,1] then what are are parameters which are going to effect as result of this splitting?

```
`input = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1,4,4,2]))
 filter = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2,2,2,1]))
 op = tf.nn.conv2d(input, filter, strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')`
```